# Magento 2 error (the shipping information was unable to be saved. verify the input data and try again )

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, shipping, magento2.3.2

How to solve an error while saving a data in checkout page in `Magento 2`

we face  an error **the shipping information was unable to be saved. verify the input data and try again** in `Magento 2.3.2` as per print screen
[enter link description here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502263947645)

Answer (score 0):

The following query helped me find the other quotes in the same situation:
SELECT entity_id, customer_id FROM quote WHERE customer_id != 0 AND customer_is_guest = 1;
Then I reset them to the proper status:
UPDATE quote SET customer_is_guest = 0 WHERE customer_id != 0 AND customer_is_guest = 1;